# AWS Lambda - Spring boot is not handling the request

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to run spring boot application as serverless in AWS lambda and I am getting below exception while calling lambda function.  Spring boot application successfully ran but it seems that it is going to fail to map the request

```
        2018-09-25 06:11:50.717 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
        2018-09-25 06:11:50.823 INFO 1 --- [ main] **my.service.Application : Started Application in 7.405 seconds (JVM running for 8.939)**
        START RequestId: decfc13c-c089-11e8-bacd-a37f1ba65629 Version: $LATEST
        2018-09-25 06:11:50.994 ERROR 1 --- [ main] **c.a.s.p.i.s.AwsProxyHttpServletRequest : Called set character encoding to UTF-8 on a request without a content type. Character encoding will not be set
        2018-09-25 06:11:51.175 ERROR 1 --- [ main] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [null]**

        java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsProxyHttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr(AwsProxyHttpServletRequest.java:575) ~[task/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1075) ~[task/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[task/:na]

        .........

        2018-09-25 06:11:51.535 ERROR 1 --- [ main] s.p.i.s.AwsLambdaServletContainerHandler : Could not forward request
```

This is my StreamLambdaHandler java file.

```
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: any update ? I got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be hitting https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/issues/172. According to the ticket, the fix will be available as part of the upcoming 1.2 release.